# Optimizing Elastic Search Index for many updates on few fields

Tags: elasticsearch

We are working on a large Elasticsearch Index (>1 bi documents) with many searchable fields evenly distributed across >100 shards on 6 nodes.

Only a few of these fields are actually changed, but they are changed very often. About 25% of total requests are changes to these fields.

We have one field that simply holds a boolean, which accounts for more than 90% of the changes done to the document.

It looks like we are taking huge performance hits re-indexing the entire documents, even though a simple boolean is changing.

Reading around I found that this might be a case where one could store the boolean value within a parent-child field, as this would effectively place it in a separate index thus not forcing a recreation of the entire document. But I also read that this comes with disadvantages, such as more heap space usage for the relation.

What would be the best way to solve this challenge?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since Elasticsearch is internally a write-only system every update effectively creates a new document and marks the old copy as stale to be garbage-collected later.

Parent-child (aka [join](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/parent-join.html)) or [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) fields can help with this but they come with a significant performance hit of their own so your search performance probably will suffer.

Another approach is to use external fast storage like Redis (as described in [this article](https://blog.bigdataboutique.com/2020/02/using-redis-as-external-scoring-source-for-elasticsearch-bjm44j)) though it would be harder to maintain and might also turn out to be inefficient for searches, depending on your use case.

General rule of thumb here is: all use cases are different and you should carefully benchmark all feasible options.